# How do I fix this elif statement with syntax error. Explanation required

Tags: python

So, I just made this weird program due to boredom called the "flex machine" (which is still being worked on), that shows some simple animation, games & projects I made one by one. In the first bit, it will ask you whether you want to see it but when you say yes, it will show syntax error on elif. Can someone help me solve this and explain what's the problem that caused it?

Code:

```
import pygame
import random
import time

# Begin the Flex
print("Yo! What's Up?")
time.sleep(2)
print("So uh since you have opened this, I will tell you what it's about")
time.sleep(2)
print("My creator got hella bored one day and found himself just scrolling through his phone too much. The only option he had was to create me")
time.sleep(2)
answer = input("So, here I am. Shall we continue? Yes or No ")
if answer == "Yes":
    print("Let's watch this cool animation that my owner gave me!")

    # Snowflake.py
    # Initialize the game engine
pygame.init()
 
BLACK = [0, 0, 0]
WHITE = [255, 255, 255]
BLUE =  [0, 0, 255]
 
# Set the height and width of the screen
SIZE = [400, 400]
 
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(SIZE)
pygame.display.set_caption("Snow Animation")
 
# Create an empty array
snow_list = []
 
# Loop 50 times and add a snow flake in a random x,y position
for i in range(50):
    x = random.randrange(0, 400)
    y = random.randrange(0, 400)
    snow_list.append([x, y])
 
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
 
# Loop until the user clicks the close button.
done = False
while not done:
 
    for event in pygame.event.get():   # User did something
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:  # If user clicked close
            done = True   # Flag that we are done so we exit this loop
 
    # Set the screen background
    screen.fill(BLACK)
 
    # Process each snow flake in the list
    for i in range(len(snow_list)):
 
        # Draw the snow flake
        pygame.draw.circle(screen, WHITE, snow_list[i], 2)
 
        # Move the snow flake down one pixel
        snow_list[i][1] += 9
 
        # If the snow flake has moved off the bottom of the screen
        if snow_list[i][1] > 400:
            # Reset it just above the top
            y = random.randrange(-50, -10)
            snow_list[i][1] = y
            # Give it a new x position
            x = random.randrange(0, 400)
            snow_list[i][0] = x
 
    # Go ahead and update the screen with what we've drawn.
    pygame.display.flip()
    clock.tick(20)
    pygame.quit()
    
elif answer == "No":
    print("Well, that's fine")
    time.sleep(2)
    print("Cya next time, have a good day")
else:
    print("Please enter yes or no.")
```

Comment: What is the error? Could you share it?

Comment: You need to indent the code below the `IF`.

Comment: Please don’t just dump your code here. Take your time to have a look at the [mcve] and [ask] pages how to best help us help you.

Comment: An elif must be part of an if suite — there does not seem to be one that belongs to the elif. Do you want to match it to the right after taking input? Are you aware that Python uses indentation to determine the grouping of statements?

Answer (score 1):

In your code, you have an `if` statement, an `elif` statement, and an `else` statement. You've indented the code within the `elif` and `else` statements properly, but seem to have forgotten to indent the code within `if` statement. Indents are required in python, so you must indent the code in the `if` statement.

I've indented the code within the statement, so it should work fine now:

```py
import pygame
import random
import time

# Begin the Flex
print("Yo! What's Up?")
time.sleep(2)
print("So uh since you have opened this, I will tell you what it's about")
time.sleep(2)
print("My creator got hella bored one day and found himself just scrolling through his phone too much. The only option he had was to create me")
time.sleep(2)
answer = input("So, here I am. Shall we continue? Yes or No ")
if answer == "Yes":
    print("Let's watch this cool animation that my owner gave me!")

    # Snowflake.py
    # Initialize the game engine
    pygame.init()
     
    BLACK = [0, 0, 0]
    WHITE = [255, 255, 255]
    BLUE =  [0, 0, 255]
     
    # Set the height and width of the screen
    SIZE = [400, 400]
     
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode(SIZE)
    pygame.display.set_caption("Snow Animation")
     
    # Create an empty array
    snow_list = []
     
    # Loop 50 times and add a snow flake in a random x,y position
    for i in range(50):
        x = random.randrange(0, 400)
        y = random.randrange(0, 400)
        snow_list.append([x, y])
     
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()
     
    # Loop until the user clicks the close button.
    done = False
    while not done:
        for event in pygame.event.get():   # User did something
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:  # If user clicked close
                done = True   # Flag that we are done so we exit this loop
     
        # Set the screen background
        screen.fill(BLACK)
     
        # Process each snow flake in the list
        for i in range(len(snow_list)):
     
            # Draw the snow flake
            pygame.draw.circle(screen, WHITE, snow_list[i], 2)
     
            # Move the snow flake down one pixel
            snow_list[i][1] += 9
     
            # If the snow flake has moved off the bottom of the screen
            if snow_list[i][1] > 400:
                # Reset it just above the top
                y = random.randrange(-50, -10)
                snow_list[i][1] = y
                # Give it a new x position
                x = random.randrange(0, 400)
                snow_list[i][0] = x
     
        # Go ahead and update the screen with what we've drawn.
        pygame.display.flip()
        clock.tick(20)
        pygame.quit()
    
elif answer == "No":
    print("Well, that's fine")
    time.sleep(2)
    print("Cya next time, have a good day")
else:
    print("Please enter yes or no.")
```

Answer (score -1):

you have to use elif only when if condition is above !
For instance .

```
if (a == 1):
    //do something
elif (a == 1):
    //do something
```

you can't do this :

```
  elif (a == 1):
    //do something
```

to fix your problem remove your first elif by if!

```
 if answer == "No":
     print("Well, that's fine")
     time.sleep(2)
     print("Cya next time, have a good day")
 else:
     print("Please enter yes or no.")
```

Answer (score -1):

Check your indentation between the first pygame.init() to the elif.